# return json_encode error from php to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to display error if username and pass is wrong.i am trying from yesterday. dont know whats wrong.every time controll goes in error and displays error.tried json.but not working.i an new in jquery ajax,

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#LoginForm").submit(function(e) {
        $("#simple-msg1").html("<img  src='img/loading.gif'/>");
        var postData ="";
        postData = $('#LoginForm').serializeArray();
        var formURL = $('#LoginForm').attr("action");

        $.ajax( {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)  {
                alert(data.error);
                if(data.error == 1) {
                    $("#simple-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data.message+'</code>< /pre>');
                } else {
                    $("#simple-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint"> Login Successfull </code></pre>');
                    window.location = "/property/Dealer/ManageProfile.php?Login=successfull";
                }
            },
            error:function(data,textStatus)  {
                $("#simple-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint"> wrong username or password 11</code></pre>');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });

    $("#Button1").click(function() {
        $("#LoginForm").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });

});

</script>
```

this is php file

```
<?php
ob_start();

if(session_id() == '')
    {
        session_start();
    }

include 'config.php';

$error = '0';
$message = 'Valid';
$redirect = 'Dealer/EditLoginDetails.php';

$myusername=$_POST['txtusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['txtpassword']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$qry = "SELECT UserName,Type_user FROM login WHERE UserName = '".$myusername."' AND password = '".$mypassword."' ";

$result = mysql_query($qry) or die ("Query failed");

$UserData = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($UserData['UserName'] != "") {
    //echo $UserData['UserName'];

    $_SESSION['UserId'] = $myusername;

    $typ = $UserData['Type_user'];

    if ( $typ == "Dealer") { 
        header('location:/Dealer/EditLoginDetails.php');  
        //echo "dealer";
        //echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
        //header('location:/Dealer/EditLoginDetails.php');
    } else if ($typ == "Individual") {
        header('location:/Dealer/EditLoginDetails.php');  

    } else {
        header('location:/Builder/managep.php'); 
    }

} else { 
    $error = '1';
    $message = 'Invalid username or password';

    // echo "forbiddnt";
    //header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    //echo " wrong username or password";
}
echo json_encode(array('error' => $error, 'message' => $message, 'redirect' => $redirect));

?>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `.serialize()` instead of `.serializeArray()`?

Comment: i have not tried this

Comment: where does this error occur?in javascript or in php?if its in php, can you provide the error message?

Comment: actually it display error  error:function(data,textStatus) this function every time.control is not going in success

Comment: inspect full request in browser console network tab...see what's sent, what's returned, status etc. And check console for errors. `serialize()` is generally what's used to send data to php

Comment: i think the error occurs because you redirect it to other php.. can you use require/include instead of header?

Comment: I don't think `header(location)` does what you want with AJAX.

Comment: most likely its redirected to other php file and served html instead. see my answer

Comment: Set the `cache` on your ajax to `false`,, may be it helps

Comment: put it before `succes`. `cache : false,`

Comment: did you use firebug? if not can you install firebug plugin in firefox.  then tell me the response body every ajax call. 

if theres no problem in the php i think the ajax cant locate the file.

Comment: You need to download Zend-eclipse-PDT and install X-Debug then you can find out the where the error is occured in PHP.i think this is  from PHP only so try this one

Answer (score 0):

My guess for the javascript error is that the header is the response being sent is not in pure json. What you can do is add `exit();` call after the `echo json_encode....` call

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code. It seems you are checking wrong values in if condition of ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#LoginForm").submit(function(e) {
    $("#simple-msg1").html("<img  src='img/loading.gif'/>");
    var postData ="";
    postData = $('#LoginForm').serializeArray();
    var formURL = $('#LoginForm').attr("action");

    $.ajax( {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)  {
            alert(data.error);
            if((data.error != '1') {
                $("#simple-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data.message+'</code>< /pre>');
            } else {
                $("#simple-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint"> Login Successfull </code></pre>');
                window.location = "/property/Dealer/ManageProfile.php?Login=successfull";
            }
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, error)  {
            $("#simple-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint"> wrong username or password 11</code></pre>');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});

$("#Button1").click(function() {
    $("#LoginForm").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});
});
</script>
```